# Creating data package for ArcGIS 9.3 in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I need to create a data package in ArcGIS 10 for a company that is using ArcGIS 9.3.

Is there any way to downgrade the versions like GDBs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Create File GDB](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_File_GDB/0017000000pw000000/) tool to create an older versions of GDB.  Then, in ArcCatalog you can copy and paste your datasets from new to old.

[image]